# Crypto++ Signing with PKCS1v15 padding with different algorithms

Tags: python, c++, pycrypto, crypto++, pycryptodome

I am wondering if Crypto++ only signs files using SHA (`RSASSA_PKCS1v15_SHA_Signer`)?

I have been using pyCryptodome to do the signing and verifying, but I want to make a C++ application that does the same. In Python, I can sign the files with any of the supported hashing (SHA3/BLAKE2B etc..) algorithms. At the very least I want to support signing using SHA256 in C++.

```cpp
std::string Hasher::sign(const std::string& message)
{
    RSASSA_PKCS1v15_SHA_Signer signer(m_privateKey);
    size_t length = signer.MaxSignatureLength();
    SecByteBlock signature(length);

    length = signer.SignMessage(rng, (CryptoPP::byte*)message.c_str(), message.size(), signature);
    signature.resize(length);
    //Want the signature as a hex
    return toHex(signature, signature.size());
}
```

However, I want to be able to do something similar I do in Python:

```py
def(message, key, passphrase, hashType):
   rsakey = RSA.importKey(key,passphrase)
   signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsakey)
   # Get the hash class based os user given hashType ex ("SHA256" returns "SHA256.New()")
   digest = getHash(hashType)
   digest.update(message.encode("ascii"))
   return signer.sign(digest).hex()
```

If I chose the same private key, and use the `hashType` "SHA" I get the same signature result as my C++ code would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found an answer to it. So partially following the tutorial found [here](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Signature_Schemes)
and from `RSASS<PSS, SHA256>::Signer signer(privateKey);` you could add the PKCS1v15 padding as such `RSASS<PKCS1v15, SHA256>::Signer signer(privateKey);`
So the final code would look something like this:

```cpp
std::string Hasher::sign(const std::string& message)
{
    CryptoPP::RSASS<CryptoPP::PKCS1v15, CryptoPP::SHA256>::Signer signer(m_privateKey);
    size_t length = signer.MaxSignatureLength();
    SecByteBlock signature(length);

    length = signer.SignMessage(rng, (CryptoPP::byte*)message.c_str(), message.size(), signature);
    signature.resize(length);
    //Want the signature as a hex
    return toHex(signature, signature.size());
}
```

So super similar, I still don't know why `RSASSA_PKCS1v15_SHA_Signer` class still exists. To throw in something extra my final goal, as I could find nothing on it except a random 13-year-old [question](https://cryptopp-users.narkive.com/NiWryVDg/how-to-sign-a-pre-calculated-hash-with-rsa-pkcs1v15) on a mailing list :
How to sign and verify a file with Crypto++ (Like you sign files in pyCrypto)

Signing file:

```cpp
std::string Hasher::sign()
{
    CryptoPP::RSASS<CryptoPP::PKCS1v15, CryptoPP::SHA256>::Signer signer(m_privateKey);

    size_t length = signer.MaxSignatureLength();
    SecByteBlock signature(length);
    // Get bytes of the file
    const auto& data = getFileBytes();
    //AFAIK you need to create a signer PK_MessageAccumulator object to acheive this
    CryptoPP::PK_MessageAccumulator* pSigMsgAcc = signer.NewSignatureAccumulator(rng);
    //Update it with your data, toBinary_const is just a short for (const CryptoPP::byte*)data.data()
    pSigMsgAcc->Update(toBinary_const(data), data.size());

    length = signer.Sign(rng, pSigMsgAcc, signature);
    signature.resize(length);
    //I return it as hex as people can actually read the signature and verify it themself
    return toHex(signature, signature.size());
}
```

Verifying a file

```cpp
bool Hasher::verify(const std::string& signature, const std::string& type)
{
    CryptoPP::RSASS<CryptoPP::PKCS1v15, CryptoPP::SHA256>::Verifier verifier(m_publicKey);

    const auto& data                             = getFileBytes();
    //Create a verifyer PK_MessageAccumulator object
    CryptoPP::PK_MessageAccumulator* pVrfyMsgAcc = verifier.NewVerificationAccumulator();
    pVrfyMsgAcc->Update(toBinary_const(data), data.size());
    //Here comes the down side of using hex as signatrue, I convert it to a binary string
    auto toVerify = toBinaryString(signature);
    //Then I have to convert the binary string to binary
    // (It does not like me to convert the hex directly to binary)
    verifier.InputSignature(*pVrfyMsgAcc, toBinary_const(toVerify), toVerify.size());
    return verifier.Verify(pVrfyMsgAcc);
}
```